# debian - pulseaudio - set microphone input volume in c++

Tags: c++

for a raspberrry applicance I need to setup the input volume of the microphone programaticaly

in c++, I can read the actual value (changed if I change it in the pa mixer), but as I set it, it does not seem to work... after I launched my code, I check in the pa panel mixer, the volume is not changed

below, the sources with their chanels and volumes

```
SOURCE : [0] 'alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Headphone_Set-00-Set.analog-stereo.monitor' 'Monitor of Audio Adapter Analog Stereo'
   (0)= 65536
   (1)= 65536
SOURCE : [1] 'alsa_input.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Headphone_Set-00-Set.analog-mono' 'Audio Adapter Analog Mono'
   (0)= 26281
SOURCE : [2] 'alsa_output.0.analog-stereo.monitor' 'Monitor of bcm2835 ALSA Analog Stereo'
   (0)= 65536
   (1)= 65536
```

so I try to change volume of source index #1

```
void setVolume(int index,int volume)
{
    pa_operation* o;
    currentVolume.values[0]=volume;
    if (!(o = pa_context_set_source_output_volume(context, index, &currentVolume, NULL, NULL))) 
    {
        printf("pa_context_set_source_output_volume() failed");
        return;
    }
    printf("new volume: %d\n",currentVolume.values[0]);
    pa_operation_unref(o);
}
```

please can someone help ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

someone answered me on the mailing list:

https://www.mail-archive.com/pulseaudio-discuss@lists.freedesktop.org/msg16025.html

> The problem is that you set the volume for a "source output" rather
>   than for a "source". A source output means a recording stream, while a
>   source is a device such as a microphone. Use
>   `pa_context_set_source_volume_by_index()` or
>   `pa_context_set_source_volume_by_name()`.